# tr focus with jQuery function

Tags: jquery, focus

I use the following function for focus on tr, and it works but I have a problem after the function is recalled when a modal window is closed because seems to work only on second click/second double click and I dont understand why.

```
function rowSelection() {
    $('table.grid> tbody > tr > td').click(function () {
        var selected = $(this).parent();
        $('table.grid> tbody > tr').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("selectedRow")) {
                $(this).removeClass("selectedRow");
            } 
        });

        if (!selected.hasClass('selectedRow')) {
            selected.addClass("selectedRow");
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone can help. 
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same with the  below code

```
$('table tbody tr').bind('click', function() 
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedRow');
});
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebG9N/2/) is the working fiddle...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but behavior is the same, on second click is applied focus.

Comment: @user1057912 Look at the link i gave in my answer. It is working fine.. If you can post the HTML that will be more helpful.

Comment: i dont understand what is the problem. this fiddle is great.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot post a html because my table is dynamically created by wicket and on the last td I have some buttons that are opening a modal window also created by wicket. So my problem is this, when I close the modal window I must recall the focus function otherwise will not work, so I already added on java page from my project the call for my function,  target.appendJavascript(" $(document).ready(function() {"+ "$('table.grid tbody tr td').click(function() {"
+" rowSelection(); return false;" + " });" + "});");, but on click, focus is added in tr after fisrt click/first double click.

Comment: And this happens only on close of modal window, onload (<body onload="rowSelection(); return false;">
) it works fine.